# new field added to sqlite table problem

Tags: database, sqlite, datatable

I added a new field (type BLOB) to an sqlite table and the table size doubled from 50mb to 100mb. the field doesn't have any data in it yet.

anyone know why this would happen?

thanks for any help.

Comment: it wasn't the new field that doubled the size. I think I was looking at a compressed version vs the uncompressed.

.sqlite file vs. ~.sqlite file

if anyone can enlighten me, that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compressing an SQLite database is done with the `VACUUM;` command (just run it as a query with sqlite3_exec if you're using the API, or directly in the console).

You can also set the database to [autovacuum](http://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_auto_vacuum), but this will slow down all modifications terribly. Better to do your operations then run the vacuum command if need be, but that's a matter of opinion.